# How to take a base frequency and create a harmonic of it using Pure Data?

Tags: puredata

I am working with extremely simple frequencies, just an `[osc~]` and a number after it. I would like to find a simple way with Pure Data to create harmonics/overtones of this frequency. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need one oscillator per overtone, and you can use simple multipliers (`* 2`, `* 3`, `* 4`, ...) to get the correct overtone frequencies. Something like this:

[image]

You can then add a `*~` after each oscillator and connect a slider to it in order to control the strength of each overtone (the slider must be set to go from `0.0` to `1.0`)

Comment: Much appreciated! Good point suggesting that the higher overtones could also be of slightly lower volume. I will accept this as an answer, and thanks for the screenshot that fully illustrated what's going on, too :)